# Calculating expected value and variance given joint Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian-integral

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X_i: \Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ random variables for $i=1,2$.

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are jointly Gaussian distributed with joint density on $\mathbb R^2$:

$$p(x,y)= \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}(\frac{(x-\mu_1)}{\sigma_1}-\frac{(y-\mu_2)}{\sigma_2})^2\right]}{2 \pi \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$$

Now I need to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ and Var($X_i)$.

So far I only have that:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\int_{\Omega}^{}X_id\mathbb{P}= \int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}xp_{X_i}dx$$

but $p_{X_i}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}p(x,y)dy$ and I don´t know how one would compute this integral or if its even possible.

Can someone help?

Comment: Your joint density looks "suspicuous". Working it out we find $\sigma_1^4$ and $\sigma_2^4$ in the expression which is uncommon. Are you sure it is okay?

Comment: Oh you are right! let me correct it, sorry!

Comment: If $(X_1,X_2)$ is supposed to be jointly normal, then  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are themselves normal.

Comment: @StubbornAtom But how do I now what expected value $X_i$ has?